# Why does my Pradicate my_flatten/2 not flatten a nested list structure? (Prolog)

Tags: list, prolog, flatten

The predicate i wrote flattens a simple list like List=[a,b,c,[d,e],f], 
but not a list like List2 = [a,b,[[c,d],e],f]. Here is my code:

```
my_flatten([], []).
my_flatten([H|T], R):- not(is_list(H)), my_flatten(T, R1), append([H], R1,  R).
my_flatten([H|T], R):- is_list(H), my_flatten(T, R1), append(H, R1, R).
```

My idea is to check whether the head is a list or not and depending on this decision to go through recursion and append the tail to the head.

Am I missing an important point?

Comment: I looked for answers but I didn't find it really helpfull according my thoughts. I think append is usefull so why don't use it. And I think that it is off topic discussing when I have to use something or not. By the way I have a solution, but I think looking at the solution without to understand why the solution is correct is not really helpfull. Important is to understand why something works or not, so I thought it would help to ask.

Comment: Listen: I am using a textbook: William F Clocksin and Christopher S. Mellish: Programming in Programming in Prolog Using the ISO Standard. I think it's unfair pretending I'm refusing to do my work, because I'm reading it, but maybe there are some points in chapter 3 (Data Structures) which are not 100 % clear. But who can you ask in your holidays? So I'm trying meanwhile learning per doing. It's really easy for you giving such comments only because you got the knowledge. Sometimes you should try to walk in other shoes, before giving comments pretending something that isn't true.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try to go on... But could you please help me according the formating of my questions? As described in the link you posted I tried to explain in a short way the Problem, I formatted the code and tried to be specific. I also tried to post the question in the title. Could you help me by telling me what I can furthermore improve?

Comment: First thing you should _always_ do if you have a problem with a predicate you are writing: **trace the execution** (use `?- trace.`)! Understanding what _your_ code does is something that you should be doing _yourself_, and you have the tools for that. Then, if there is something in the trace you don't understand, put the relevant part of the trace in your question and ask why does it do what it does and not what you expect.

Comment: I already tried trace and I really like the GUI Trace function and I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to write the solution in prolog.

Comment: If you have a trace, put it in your question and point to the exact problem. Ask where the problem comes from and how to solve it.

Comment: okay got it for the next time.

Comment: Just an FYI: `append([H], R1, R)` is the same as `[H|R1] = R`, which means your second clause can reduce to: `my_flatten([H|T], [H|R1]):- not(is_list(H)), my_flatten(T, R1).`

Comment: okay this means writing like this helps the program to be efficient because append uses a lot of capacity, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing an important point?

yes, of course. Boris is right that you will learn more if you try to find the problem yourself. Just an hint: you must recurse on the head, when it's a list, to get it flattened.

After that (just add a call in proper place in last clause) and you'll get

```
?- my_flatten([a,b,[[c,d],e],f], L).
L = [a, b, c, d, e, f] ;
false.
```

Comment: solved it: my_flatten([H|T], R):- is_list(H),my_flatten(H, R1), my_flatten(T, R2), append(R1, R2, R). It works! Thank you!